# Bad Request Error When handling a form in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am creating a change password form in my flask application. I ask a security question (which the user made when they signed up). I have the user input the answer into a html form. Then I am trying to compare the users input to the answer stored in the database.

I am getting this error:

> 400 Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

I have been looking through similar threads and they all say to make sure that the name in the input tag is spelled the same as the name in request.form[''] which mine is.

I appreciate any suggestions on where to go from here. I have been struggling with this for a few days now.

This is my python code:

```
@app.route('/contchangepassword/' , methods=["GET","POST"])
def cont_change_password():

    if request.method == "POST":
        c, conn = connection()
        user_id = session['the_id'] #this is the users id 
        question = session['question'] #this is the question the user made and it was retreived from the database
        attempted_password = request.form['answer'] #this is getting the input from the html form

        x = c.execute("""SELECT * FROM user_secuirty WHERE id = (%s)""", [user_id])


        #this is seeing if the user exists. if the user exists then this message will be flashed    
        if int(x) == 0:
            flash ("user does not exists")
            return render_template('contchangepassword.html',question = question)

        else:
            #getting the answer from the database
            c.execute("""SELECT answer FROM user_secuirty WHERE id = (%s)""", [user_id])
            password = c.fetchone()[0]

            #this is comparing both passwords (the password in the database was hashed) 
            if sha256_crypt.verify(attempted_password, password):

                session['secuirty_correct'] = True
                session['user_id'] = user_id

                return render_template('contchangepassword.html', question=question)

            else:
                flash("Incorrect password to security question.")
                return render_template('contchangepassword.html', question=question)
                c.close()
                conn.close()
                gc.collect()



    return render_template('contchangepassword.html', question=question)
```

this is my html:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post">
        <h1 class="form-signin-heading">Answer Your Security Question</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;font-weight:800;">{{question}}?</p>
        <label for="secuirty_answer" class="sr-only">secuirty_answer</label>
        <input type="text" name="answer" class="form-control" placeholder="Place Answer Here" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" style="margin-bottom:5px;" value="Login" type="submit">Continue</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: if anyone uses this to compare to theirs. The reason why it was not working is because in the form tags I did not put an action=""

Comment: This is what it looks like now                                                                       `<form class="form-signin"  action="/contchangepassword/" method="post">
         </form>`